# Cant seem to hit Public URL web service from phonegap through an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have added the following internet functionality in the config.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Now, I want to send some data to a public IP URL(I have given the local IP in the code for security reasons) in post in an ajax call.
I am using a phonegap server hosted locally. The server is not getting hit (checked in the access logs).
Following is the code I am using.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="searchform"  name="searchform">
    <a   onclick="msearchByTracking()"><p class="search" style="border: none; width:45px; height:35px">&nbsp;</p></a>
        <input class="searchbox" id="hashtag" name="hashtag" type="text" placeholder="search">

    </form>

<script>
    function msearchByTracking(){
        var hashtag = document.getElementById("hashtag").value;
        alert(hashtag);
        var url="http://192.168.1.15/Square/Search/hashtagSearch/search.php";
        /* var data = {'keyword'=hashtag};
         console.log('console.log'+JSON.stringify(data)); */
         var datastring="keyword="+hashtag;
            alert(datastring);
         $.ajax({
           url: url,
           type: "POST",
           contentType:"application/json",
           dataType:"json",
           data:datastring,
           success: function(data){
             //On ajax success do this
             alert(data);
              },
           error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              //On error do this
                if (xhr.status == 200) {

                    alert(ajaxOptions);
                }
                else {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            }

         });

    }
    app.initialize();
</script>
```